# Missing package name Error with vue cli install from tar

Tags: vue.js, npm-install

I am behind a corporate proxy and so am installing npm packages via the downloaded tar files. It's worked just fine for alot of packages, however, I have come across the following error when attempting to install the Vue CLI:

`Can't install ... Missing package name`

I have not found much reference to this error elsewhere. Wondering if someone can point me in a direction on this.

Comment: maybe this can help: `npm config set strict-ssl false`

Comment: Thx but error persists